# How to maintain state between ASP.NET MVC4 Applications in Same Domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I am new to MVC and I have been  given a task to maintain state between applications that are in same domain - cookie would be one option ,Is there any alternate option other than cookie storage ?

Comment: The approach you take depends on the amount of data you want to share & what type of data - simple values or complex types.

Comment: data Related to user -  so that the user can login to other application with same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by setting the domain name in web.config

```
<httpCookies domain=".domain.com"/>
```

Comment: Hi yousuf, you mean just with this httpcookie entry in config file would be enough to maintain state. one of my scenario is that I have my login details in a session for app1, and I am able to access the same login details through cookie session in another App2, but when I tried to logout App1, App2 still could access login credentials. I am looking for some other option other than cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There are several

1) Running a state server

2) Using sql server to store state
   a) doing this in the web.config

3) Using some sort of Database server (mssql/nosql/oracle/...) (this is my preference. Because you do not need to rely on Microsoft to correctly save state in 1 or more db)
   a)saving a guid to the cookie and then saving the important state data you need to sql server

Comment: Here is the situation, due to some infrasture issue we don't have an option to use any DB server for storage- only inproc mode

Comment: If you are just wanting to auth a user between mutliple sites within a domain, you will need to persist the auth data somewhere. Since must sites use a db why not just persist the data to the db in table. For example. have a login table, that stores the guid you authed the user with and the expiration of that guid along with what permissions they have. If you told/need to use cookies only then you will need to encrypt some sort of passphrase saying they are authed for time x. and decrypt that every time they make a request. Using the db is safer and simpler